# How to submit form to same page and get results displayed

Tags: php, mysql

I have this form

```
<form action="" method="GET" id="formSearch">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSearch" name="inputSearch"/>
                <span id="spanBtnSearch" class="input-group-btn">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSearch" value="Search"/>
                </span>
            </div>          
        </form>
```

I want to send this form on the same page and my connection and query is below

```
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost:3311","root","root","compared");
$shingpoint = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE store LIKE 'shingpoint' AND title LIKE '%".$_POST['inputSearch']."%'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$shingpoint);
?>
```

And the results that should show the results is this

```
<div class="row" id="divShingpoint">
        <h2 class="section-title style2 text-left">Shingpoint</h2>
        <div id="divProductThumbnail" class="item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 colums">
            <div class="container" id="divInnerContainer">
            <?php while ($shingpointrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {?>
                <div class="product">
                    <div class="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $shingpointrow['img'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $shingpointrow['title']?>"/></div>
                    <div class="description"><h4 class="productname"><?php echo substr(trim($shingpointrow['title']),0,20) ?></h4></div>
                    <div class="price">
                        <span><?php echo $shingpointrow['price'] ?></span>
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Details"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php }?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It does send data as the page refreshes and url is updated but results don't get displayed on the div with the title I want to search.

And I am getting this error

Notice: Undefined index: inputSearch in C:\wamp64\www\compareit.php on line 3

What is missing what am i doing wrong? Or there is any other method to accomplish the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the method to be GET but you try to read from $_POST.

So either change your `<form method="POST">` or `$_POST['inputSearch']` replace with `$_GET['inputSearch']`.

Other than that I would add some validation, use PDO and change few more things...

Answer (score 0):

Your form should have **post** method rather then **get**